# fitch proof. P v Q, Q→ ¬ R, ¬ P, ¬ R → ¬ S GOAL: ¬ S

Tags: proof, symbolic-logic, fitch

Need help exercise using the FITCH program format. I'm stuck on where to start. The following 4 steps must be used to prove the goal.

```
P v Q
Q→ ¬ R
¬ P
¬ R → ¬ S
```

GOAL: ¬ S

Now I know: ¬ P and P v Q is true - hence, Q is true. Q is true and Q→ ¬ R is true. As true implies true statement, ¬ R is true. ¬ R → ¬ S is true. Since true never implies a false statement ¬ S is true. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Isn't that already the proof? As PvQ is true and as P is not true you know that Q must be true and as from Q follows not R you get not R from which follows not S qed. So the problem isn't were to start but how to write that in this weird system right?

Comment: Could anyone please edit the formatting of the question to make it a bit more polished? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use **Disjunction Elimination** (Proof by cases). As **P v Q** is one of your premises, assume P and derive a sentence, then assume Q and derive that same sentence; you are now allowed to discharge it. The only remaining step is using **Implication Elimination** to reach the goal.

```
1. |  P v Q         
2. |  Q → ¬ R       
3. |  ¬ P           
4. |_ ¬ R → ¬ S     
5. |  |_ P          
6. |  |  ⊥          ⊥ Intro: 5,3
7. |  |  ¬ R        ⊥ Elim: 6
8. |  |_ Q          
9. |  | ¬R          → Elim: 2,8
10.|  ¬R            v Elim: 1, 5-7,8-9
11.| ¬ S            → Elim: 4,10
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm unsure if my edits above are correct.

Comment: If you meant **Negation Elimination** (where you wrote INTRO), then that step is correct. I do not understand the step where you annotated elim (6). Can you clarify ?

Comment: elim ⊥ is eliminate in reference to step 6 (the step before). And the reit is reiterating premise 2

Comment: In step 6, you are deriving P v Q, but that is one of your premises. Can you use **Explosion** rule ? Also, no need to reiterate premise 2, I think. Does your system require that step ?

Comment: No, I can't use Explosion rule. Disjunction Elimination is certainly correct, but I'm not sure how to add it on Fitch

Comment: I have added a photo of what I currently have

Comment: Fitch?  Ah, are you using Stanford's Implementation? There Explosion is done by: `¬Q→¬P` and `¬Q→P` entail `¬¬Q` by *negation introduction*, and `¬¬Q` entails `Q` by *negation elimination*.

Comment: @Graham Kemp, I think he is using LPL system and Explosion rule is called **⊥ Elim**.

Comment: @eaglefern, I just completed the proof using LPL system. I think it is correct, now.

Comment: @F. Zer, thank you!!!!! yes it works.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I know: ¬ P and P v Q is true - hence, Q is true. Q is true and Q→ ¬ R is true. As true implies true statement, ¬ R is true. ¬ R → ¬ S is true. Since true never implies a false statement ¬ S is true. I just don't know where to start.

That is basically it.  The only question is whether you can use the rule of Disjunctive Syllogism, or need to build a proof by cases using fundamental rules of inference.

```
 a.| ¬P 
 b.| P v Q
   :
 c.| Q       DS a, b        | Disjunctive Syllogism
   :
   :
 d.|  |_ P   A              | Proof by Cases
 e.|  |  #   ¬E d,a         |
 f.|  |  Q   X  e           |
   :                        |
 g.|  |_ Q   A              |
   :                        |
 h.|  Q      vE b,d-f,g-g   |
```